# Bt audio works, but absolutely no GUI

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, usb-audio

I have a BT audio device:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0a12:1275 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd HaiSenKeJi
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0a12:4010 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
```

In sound settings I can select it for output:

[image]

Now the problem is that I can't get any GUI to show which speaker is my computer connected to.

I installed *everything* I found: bluetooth*, bluez*, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth, blueman*.

However, normal bluetooth commands doesn't work as they can't find an adapter.

What am I supposed to do to get some GUI?

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you expect the GUI to do? The sound settings already show which sound output is selected.

Comment: Please run `(sudo lsusb -v -d 0a12:1275; sudo lsusb -v -d 0a12:4010) > /tmp/bt-usb-description.txt` and then post the contents of the `/tmp/bt-usb-description.txt` to a pastebin somewhere (it may be quite long) and add a link to it in your original question.  Although the USB transmitter might use Bluetooth, it seems it does not work like a generic Bluetooth transmitter, but might be presenting a *USB-Audio* interface instead. Unfortunately that would most likely mean you'd need vendor-specific software to pair it, which might not exist for Linux.